# Readonly variable vs Readonly-Typed method in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, typescript, readonly

### What is the difference between Readonly variable and Readonly-Typed Method in typescript?

**Readonly Variable**

```
length: Readonly<Number | number | String | string> = 1;
```

vs

**Readonly-typed Method**

```
length(lenght: Number | number | String | string): Readonly<Number | number | String | string> {
        var width: Readonly<Number | number | String | string> = lenght;
        return width;
    }
```

> - What are the difference's for those thinks?
> - And is it possible to assign value for `Readonly` function on runtime?

Comment: but it isn't a readonly method - its a method that returns a readonly-typed variable.

Comment: OOPS! I have update my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Readonly<T>` [is an object-type mapping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types):

```
type Readonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};
```

It will make all properties of `T` appear read-only to the compiler - So it doesn't actually make sense to use it on either `number` or `string` to begin with, because neither have properties.

if you want a true read-only --but internally changeable-- property at run-time then use a getter.

```
interface IFoo {
  readonly length: number;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
  private _length: number;

  get length(): number {
    return this._length;
  }

  change(length: number) {
    this._length = length;
  }
}
```

There is no difference between a variable typed `Readonly<T>` and a method that returns a variable typed `Readonly<T>` bar the extra step of using a method.